# Adding motion sensor to outdoor lights

Tags: motion-sensor

I’m planning to add 2 motion sensors for flood lights and porch lights (to automatically turn lights from porch or driveway). Currently my flood lights connected to 3 may switch and porch to 2 way switch. However,I don’t have red wire in my lights junction boxes and I can’t see where red wire connected from 3 way switch. Do I need to run new red wires to all lights and replace 2 way switch to 3 way? Can I use 12 gauge for red wire? Is there any other solutions/ recommendations? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you'd have a three-way switch and a two-way switch on the same light loop. Are you sure?

Comment: Can you post a sketch and or pictures.